# Exclude css & image resources in web.xml Security Constraint

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets, web.xml

I am using JSF2.1 and Glassfish 3.1.2.

I specify a security constraint to block everything:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured Content</web-resource-name>
        <!-- Block all -->
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <!-- only users with at least one of these roles are allowed to access the secured content -->
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and have another to allow access a subset of pages and the resources:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Open Content</web-resource-name>
        <!-- Allow subscribe -->
        <url-pattern>/subscribe/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- No Auth Contraint! -->
</security-constraint>
```

This works fine. However, is the following

```
<url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
```

the correct way to allow all resources?

I only did this by looking at the url that Facelets injects into the xhtml. Is there security holes with this approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to be the value of [`ResourceHandler#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER) constant. See also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER):

> ## `RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`
>
> `public static final java.lang.String RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`
>
> `Resource#getRequestPath` returns the value of this constant as the prefix of the URI. [`handleResourceRequest(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#handleResourceRequest%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) looks for the value of this constant within the request URI to determine if the request is a resource request or a view request.
>
> #### See Also:
>
> [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)

The [constant field values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER) says the following:

```
public static final java.lang.String    RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER    "/javax.faces.resource"
```

So, you're absolutely correct as to the URL pattern. There are no security holes, provided that you don't put sensitive information in `/resources` folder of the public webcontent which is handled by the JSF resource handler.